# Are there Cessna spare parts supplier in South East Asia?

Tags: cessna-172

I am living in South East Asia, and thinking of buying a reconditioned Cessna 172. Are there any spare parts supplier here that I could purchase , or do I need to order from US ?

Answer (score 2):

Something like 8.5% of the world's population live in south east asia, and the Cessna 172 is [the world's most produced aircraft](https://flyfa.com/the-most-produced-aircraft-is-cessna-172-17-facts-about-cessna-172/). While the details depend on what country you're in (e.g. I suspect getting spares for a US built aircraft is harder in myanmar / burma, for example) if there's a place where you could get spares and (far more importantly) a qualified mechanic, it's very likely that they'll have come across the Cessna 172 before. It's the archetypical civil general aviation aircraft, and in the (unlikely) event that you need something specific and exotic that your local area doesn't have, spares are very common worldwide and Fedex is comparatively cheap – at least in comparison to aircraft parts!

Answer (score 1):

If I were in your shoes, I would start here, at [Textron Aviation’s locate service portal](https://txtav.com/en/service/locator).  To purchase a new Cessna aircraft, you can [locate a Textron/Cessna sales rep in your area](https://txtav.com/sales) here.  There appears to be a Textron service center in Singapore and they will probably be able to help you there.

Keep in mind, for many countries in that area of the world it may be difficult to find service or spare parts. Light airplanes are kind of a first world luxury item and most OEMs are not going to spend the money on maintaining facilities in parts of the world where people cannot afford them.  Countries whose governments are communist and/or have unfriendly relations with the USA present even more difficulties (if you live in the DPRK, you might be able to buy [the Dear Leader-approved, and unauthorized, local built C172 clone](https://youtu.be/maF-5PHUyTI).) You would either have to go to Singapore or Australia or some other place where major repair and overhaul facilities are available.